# connect to the internet using java

Tags: java, windows

Whenever i want to connect to internet,i double click a connection icon(i created it earlier where username and password(for broadband) are stored) and click connect.The icon is in the network places(Windows XP)

May i know how to launch this connection from java or any other language? (I am asking this because my Internet Service Provider doesn't charge anything between 2 AM and 8AM :-)  )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to be unnecessarily difficult with Java, I believe. You'd have to write some native code to do the job for you, at which point you may as well write your whole program in C# or C++ anyway.

But, since you asked for a Java approach, you might want to look at the [Robot](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class. It lets you move the mouse to a specific location on the screen, click, and otherwise automate the manual actions that you are doing. It's a very fragile solution.

Alternatively, if you can figure out what command the network connection shortcut is invoking, you can directly invoke it from Java using [Runtime.exec](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29).

(I don't really see why Java is good for this task, though.)

Answer (score 3):

Creating a system task to run the program.  You shouldn't need Java to execute a program on windows.

To use Scheduled Tasks in XP: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569